# Как найти всех пользователей с именем, начинающимся на нужную букву?

Tags: sql

Есть таблица users, в ней поля id, user и т.д. Подскажите, каким запросом можно выбрать всех пользователей, имя которых начинается на букву А ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

А `LIKE` чем не подходит ?

```
  SELECT user FROM users WHERE user LIKE 'A%'
```

Вот и все =)

Comment: И вам спасибо. Ну не то чтобы LIKE не подходил.. просто я вообще не знал что использовать)

Comment: Ну на то мы все и учимся =)

Answer (score 0):

`SELECT user FROM users REGEXP "^[A]";` Но могу ошибаться...

Comment: Спасибо) Не подскажите, где можно подробно прочитать про REGEXP?

Comment: Ну для такой банальщины нет смысла использовать регулярные выражения.

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/regexp.html#operator_regexp